# Save Winform MS Chart as an SVG

Tags: c#, winforms, svg, mschart

Is it possible to render an image with an svg format from a MS Chart?

I've tried to use png, bmp and jpg, but the resolution was to poor.

current code:

```
chart1.SaveImage(Path.GetFullPath(@"Charts/" + "chart1.bmp"), ChartImageFormat.Bmp);
```

Comment: what is the size of your chart ?

Comment: There's an [SVG Rendering Engine](https://github.com/vvvv/SVG) on GitHub. Also available as [NuGet Package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Svg/). Never tested. Check also this SO question [Saving higher resolution charts without messing up the appearance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9641436/saving-higher-resolution-charts-without-messing-up-the-appearance).

Comment: @MongZhu the size is 600x300 px

Comment: Thanks @Jimi I'll check that

Comment: You can directly save as emf; there should be transformers that bring it to svg. Of course the resolution is strictly up to you. You can make the chart larger, save to png and make the file's dpi larger. Results are great but for vector you need to go with emf.